# get finger print JPEG image from Android device authentication scanner

Tags: android, fingerprint

Is there any sample code for get a finger print image (JPEG,PNG..etc) from android device(XOLO Q2100) with inbuilt finger print scanner 
any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

to do this you have to use external finger print device with its own SDK. Mobile finger print scanner will never output in jpg/png format. it is an hardly secure in android where finger print value exist in encrypted format.